# Проблема с манифестом

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest, manifest

как то незаменто при компиляции появилась ошибка. Прошу помочь т.к вообще понятия не имею в чём проблема. В интернете решения не вижу. Вот ошибка: `Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED
Installation failed due to: 'null'`
Манифест:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.homecontrol">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />

        <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".alarms"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.homecontrol"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решается переходом в подменю *Run/Debug Configuration*, вам нужно изменить *You app > General > Installation Options > Install Flags* путем добавления флагов `-r -t` которые означают команду: `adb install -r -t apkpath`. Чтобы было понятнее и нагляднее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57589248/installation-failed-due-to-null-android-studio-3-5) вопрос по вашей проблеме.